# Many to Many relationships laravel -mongo

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-4, many-to-many

Hi i'm newbie in laravel and mongodb. I code some relations about Team, User and Board in many-many relationship. but it's not work ! what should i do in controller.

(i use jenssegers/laravel-mongodb https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb))

Relation is    User 1..* --- * Team * ----1..* Board

#### User (Model)

```
class User extends ...

public function teams()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('Team', null, 'teamMembers', 'teams');
}
```

#### Board (Model)

```
class Taskboard extends ...
public function teams()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('Team', null, 'taskboards', 'teams');
}
```

#### Team (Model)

```
class Team extends ...
public function teamMembers()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('User', null, 'teams', 'teamMembers');
}
public function taskboards()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('Taskboard', null, 'teams', 'taskboards');
}
```

#### Controller Team // OK work!

```
   public function store()
   {
    $team = new Team;
    $team->name = Input::get('teamname');
    $team->master =  Auth::user()->_id;
    $team =  Auth::user()->teams()->save($team);  // OK just work!
    $team->save();
    return Redirect::route('main');
    }
```

#### Controller Board // Have a problem

```
public function store()
{
 $taskboard = new Taskboard;
 $taskboard->name = Input::get('boardname');
 $taskboard->teams = Input::get('team');

 $taskboard = Auth::user()->teams()->save(taskboard);  // Not work! What should I do to store boards in team

 return Redirect::route('main');
 }
```

Comment: is this a typo? save(taskboard); missing $ from taskboard?

Comment: $taskboard not work too.